# E: Unable to locate package php7.2-bcmath

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, php-7.2

I'm trying to install package php7.2-bcmath on Ubuntu 14.4

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-bcmath'
```

I already try those options:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath
```

add this to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main universe
```

**Nothing works!**

**Please help**

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo()` to see if it is already there?

Comment: Yes. it's not there.

Comment: What do you get for `sudo apt-get install php-bcmath`?

Comment: @NigelRen The same result. E: Unable to locate package php-bcmath

Comment: BTW: this is a duplicate question, which is also posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193954/e-unable-to-locate-package-php7-2-bcmath I'm sure, that askubuntu is the better place for this, because this topic is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should check which PHP version is available and if you addressed the correct package name.

Use:

```
apt-cache search php
```

to check, if PHP7.2 and all the extensions are available at your environment.

Determine the correct package name of the bcmath package by searching trough all available packages:

```
apt-cache search php | grep bcmath
```

If you see an bcmath package for php7.2 use this name with the `sudo apt-get install ....` syntax.

Comment: Make sure, that you search is case insensitive. Use `grep -i bcmath`. If the package is not shown in `apt-cache search php `so you know, that this package is not available in on of your repositories.

Comment: This package exists. but, it's not available

Comment: you only can install packages, that are shown in your apt environment. If it is not show (as you wrote in your comment) than is not available for your configuration.